# Target must be a dense double array of node indices. How to Solve?

Tags: matlab, graph, network-analysis

I am trying to build a network graph with [word adjacency](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/netdata/) data. But I am getting the error "Target must be a dense double array of node indices". Following is my code:

```
fileName = 'adjnoun.gml';
inputfile = fopen(fileName);
A=[];

l=0;
k=1;
while 1

    % Get a line from the input file
    tline = fgetl(inputfile);

    % Quit if end of file
    if ~ischar(tline)
        break
    end

    nums = regexp(tline,'\d+','match'); %get number from string
    if length(nums)
        if l==1
            l=0;
            A(k,2)=str2num(nums{1});
            k=k+1;
            continue;
        end
        A(k,1)=str2num(nums{1});
        l=1;
    else
        l=0;
        continue;
    end
end
A= sort(A);
g = graph(A(:,1),A(:,2));
```

A is 425X2 double matrix. When I am trying to create the graph `g = graph(A(:,1),A(:,2))`, it is throwing the error.

Comment: Have you checked the elements of `A` are what you expect? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matlab's `graph(s, t)` function will display that error if you have 0's in your source or target arrays. In other words, if `A(:, 2)` contains any zeros, Matlab will fail with the displayed error. You could:

i. Add "1" to all of your values with: `A=A+1`

ii. Modify your original graph to produce a .gml output without zeros.